# subview not blending with superview

Tags: iphone, uiview

I want to include a searchbar in the navigation bar of a scene.

Using this code, I successfully put the searchbar in the navigation bar.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView *titleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 0, 150, 40)];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView;

    UISearchBar *mynewsb = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,150,40)];

    mynewsb.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
    mynewsb.opaque = NO;

    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:mynewsb];
}
```

However, when I run the app, I get this.

[image]

**You can see the background of the search bar is still discernable.** It has not blended with the titleView. BTW the two bar button items were added using a storyboard.

I tried these codes but no success.

```
mynewsb.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.0];
mynewsb.opaque = NO;
```

What can I do in order to blend the search bar background nicely with the titleView?

Comment: to blend it try setting tint color to transparent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Height of Title Bar is 44.

So use CGRectMake(35, 0, 150, 44) or CGRectMake(0,0,150,44) instead of 40.